# Debugging GTM in Google Tag Assistant while the GMT script is embedded in an iframe on a different domain

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, cross-domain, google-tag-manager

I'm having a weird issue with the GTM's debugging feature in that is suddenly stopped working after the interface was revamped.

Before, I was able to preview my tags by simply adding the website's url and the debugger would successfully connect to the web app.

Now, after entering the url, the website is opened in a new tab and the google tag assistant times out after a minute with a 'Could not connect message' all while the Google Tag Assistant is connected in the iframe.

[could not connect message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMh9Y.png)

[debugger connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uU8TT.png)

I must add that I'm using Chrome with the Google Tag Assistant extension installed and I'm not experiencing any issues with the tags themselves or with the GA integration.

> Interoperability with the Tag Assistant Chrome extension
> The Tag Assistant chrome extension operates as a companion to the extension-less debugger. When the Chrome extension is present, the following features are enabled:
> Detection of a global site tag inside an iframe.

What I was able to find out so far is that the issue does not strictly arrise from the fact that the GTM script is embedded within an iframe, but that the iframe is on a different domain than the top window. I changed the domain of the iframe on a development environment to match the top window one and the google tag assistant was able to connect successfully to the web app without any issues.

The documentation on this particular case is somewhat lacking and I was not able to find any support on the wild wild web.

Any input would be appreciated,
Thank you!

Comment: it looks like that after the upgrade there are several issues right now.. we also have strang tracking problems since their upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Found a dirty workaround:

1. click preview in Google Tag Manager
2. delete any existing domains if any
3. add a new domain (the iframe's domain)
4. don't close the newly opened tab
5. switch back to the  Tag Assistant tab, close the connection with the iframe so it will take you to the previous window where you can add new domains
6. add a new domain (this time the domain that contains the iframe)
7. switch back to the Tag Assistant tab and enable the unknown connection prompt (from behind de modal with the connecting attempt)
8. you should now be able to debug

repeat these steps every time

best of luck